# Dropdown field with user inserted data into another form (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, configuration

I was wondering if it was possible to put user inserted data into a dropdown text field for example:

I have the form for let's say what you did in a day, start hour end hour etc and activity, now I want the activity field to be a drop down one and have user data exclusive to the user currently logged in that was inputed into a "configuration" form, so you dont have to remember the activity number,

how can I do this?

Is this even possible?

using RoR

Comment: Can you provide more information with code ?

Comment: for example:  <%= f.select :atividade, ['I want this to be a select function in my db'], {}, {class: "dropdown"}%>

Comment: It is very simple. Can you provide code which you done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### inside your controller

```
  def new
    ..
    prepare_item
  end

  def edit
    ..
    prepare_item
  end

  def prepare_item
    @item_list = Items.all.map  { |c| [c.name, c.id] } 
  end
```

#### inside your view

```
<%= f.select :item_id, @item_list, { include_blank: false }, { class: 'form-control' } %>
```

- please note class: form-control incase you using bootstrap

Comment: Thanks! I'm still generating the code, will get back to you soon

Comment: quick question can the "c" be any letter I want? or must it be c

Comment: it can be any letter/word,  that only variabel name for looping inside map block

Comment: I want to add this to the item "tarefa / tarefas" how should I apply the code?

Comment: Ok, the above code usually for "one to many connection" for example tarefa has many items, then after you create model connection the controller above is for tarefa controller to access items (other model) BTW: sorry I'm not clear what tarefa is :-)

Comment: I did `@tarefa_list = Tarefa.where(user_id: current_user) { |c| [c.Numero][c.Resumo]}` but instead of showing Numero followed by Resumo it shows `#<Tarefa:0xc201ae0>`

Comment: you missing .map @tarefa_list = Tarefa.where(user_id: current_user).map 
{ |c| [c.Numero][c.Resumo]}